# Prevent folder creation in SharePoint Online (SharePoint 2013) (including Explorer view)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, folder, remote-event-receiver

I am new to SharePoint programming and I found this online:

https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/prevent-creating-folder-in-sharepoint-document-library-and-list/

It appears to be from SharePoint 2010 as SharePoint 2013 now uses Remote Event Receivers in Visual Studio 2015 (through a SharePoint Add-In project).

Is there something similar or is there a way to "transfer" this code to SharePoint Online (currently on SharePoint 2013)?

We use Office 365 and we do not have access to a on premise SharePoint installation.

Thank you for your time and help in advance.